# Posting JSON to NodeJS server shows success when it is actually a failure

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, okhttp

Here is my android code to post to my nodejs server

```
registrationjson.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
registrationjson.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String jsonfromForm = gson.toJson(registrationjson);

                    client = new OkHttpClient();
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonfromForm);
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(uri)
                            .post(body)
                            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                            .build();

                    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            System.out.println("Failure!!");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                            System.out.println("Success!!");
                        }
                    });
```

When I trigger the above code, I get `Success` printed out in the console even though the server returns respond status of 400 as it is shown below (from the logs) :

```
2017-05-08T06:03:36.358142+00:00 app[web.1]: Request Received:  5/8/2017 6:3:36
2017-05-08T06:03:36.358391+00:00 app[web.1]: Registration Request Received:  5/8/2017 6:3:36
2017-05-08T06:03:36.370211+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /users/register 400 8.328 ms - 11
```

and when I change `System.out.println("Success!!");` to `System.out.println(response.toString());` I get the following printed in the console:

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
05-08 10:10:20.005 4325-4632/ I/System.out: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=URL}
```

so it detects the error but it doesn't execute the code inside onFailure,

when onFailure is executed? or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**

```
   System.out.println(response.toString()); // wrong way
```

**Do**

To convert the java objects to **JSON** format, use **`toJson()`** method.

```
   System.out.println(""+new Gson().toJson(response));
```

Comment: I got you, but its not the answer of my question, anyway it prints out messy JSON with hundreds of words starting with `I/System.out: {"body":{"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Server","Cowboy","Connection","keep-alive","X-Powered-By","Express"`,

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi it prints out messy JSON with hundreds of words starting with`GSON onResponse method fetches whole JSON .

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi what you want ??

Comment: my onFailure method is not executed, even though the response status code is 400. Why?

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi did you try with ? `if (response.code() == 400)`?

Comment: I know of the possibility of this solution but then I will have to implement it on onResponse method, and onFailure would be useless then